# .Net maui database import need way to reload application / close application

Tags: database, exit, restart, maui, filepicker

I have recently added an import/export database feature to my app. I am looking for a way to quit and reload my .net maui application after an import has been done. I am having issues just trying to quit the application with Application.Current.Quit. Suggestions?

Also, are there any easy ways to set up a file picker on Maui to prevent hard coding file paths?

Comment: iOS and Android frown upon forced restarts - is there not a more elegant way you can do this without restarting the app?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't actually need to restart the app?

In your cross-platform `App.xam.cs` App constructor, there is a line something like `MainPage = new MainPage();`.  You can do the equivalent from anywhere:

```cs
Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
```

Also, looking at [App lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle), you might add code to be performed when app starts up or shuts down. Refactor those so you can call them explicitly:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnResumed()
    {
        MyOnResumed();
    }
    public void MyOnResumed()
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnStopped()
    {
        MyOnStopped();
    }
    public void MyOnStopped()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you could perform that cleanup and initialization:

```cs
    var app = Application.Current as MyNameSpace.App;
    app.MyOnStopped();
    app.MainPage = new MainPage();
    app.MyOnResumed();
```

The goal is to write your app in such a way that any necessary cleanup and initialization is performed in those two methods.